# yii blog captcha never verifies

Tags: php, yii

Im trying to integrate captcha with the Yii blog (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/) so that users have to fill out a captcha in the comment form. 
In the comment form view i have added

```
    <?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()): ?>
    <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
            <div>
            <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('captchaAction'=>'comment/captcha')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="hint">Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.
            <br/>Letters are not case-sensitive.</div>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I have added this array to accessRules() in comment controller:

```
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                    'actions'=>array('index','view', 'captcha'),
                    'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
```

And I override actions() in CommentController:

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xD99D25,
        ),
    );
}
```

To the Comment model, I have added a new rule:

```
array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'on' => 'insert', 'allowEmpty'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
```

and new public member:

```
public $verifyCode;
```

Because the comment form is displayed from the blog actionView(), I think it creates a problem. The captcha displays but never validates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add the captchaAction to your Comment model validation rule, like this:

```
array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'on' => 'insert', 'allowEmpty'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest, 'captchaAction'=>'comment/captcha')
```